# Adding Gravity behavior to multiple objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollisionbehavior, uigravitybehavior

I am building a game in which there are lots of square blocks floating around the screen, bouncing off each other, walls, etc until they get destroyed.  Currently, I have a master `UIGravityBehavior` and I add each square (a `UIView` class called SquareView) as it's created, then remove it when it's destroyed. But I *think* I should be doing this inside the SquareView object.  Here's the relevant code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollisionBehaviorDelegate  {
    var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
```

...

```
// next sequence adds a square
let newSquare = SquareView()
newSquare.createSquare(touch.locationInView(view).x, y: touch.locationInView(view).y)
view.addSubview(newSquare)
gravity.addItem(newSquare)
```

...

```
// this removes a square
gravity.removeItem(currentSquare)
```

So I believe I should be moving this code outside of the `ViewController` into my definition of my SquareView class:

```
func createSquare(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat){
    self.backgroundColor = color[touchCount]
    self.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: size[touchCount], height: size[touchCount])
}
```

Incidentally, I do the same thing with `UICollisionBehavior` and assume that's not optimal as well.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Not an answer to your question but, have you taken a look at [Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SpriteKitFramework_Ref/index.html)? Sprite Kit is much more suited for games than straight UIKit.